# How to use apply() with my function

Tags: r, function, apply

```
bmi<-function(x,y){
(x)/((y/100)^2)
}
```

bmi(70,177) it can work

but with apply() it does't work

```
apply(Student,1:2,bmi(Student$weight,Student$height))
```

Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
'bmi(Student$weight, Student$height)' is not a function, character or symbol

[image]

Comment: Your function is already vectorized so you don't need `apply`, just `bmi(Student$weight,Student$height)`

Comment: Adding to what @docendodiscimus just said. `Student$bmi <- bmi(Student$weight, Student$height)` if you want a column with bmi.

Comment: `apply(Student, 1, function(x) bmi(x["weight"], x["height"]))`, but it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what the goal is. If it's just to get an answer, then the comments do answer it. If on the other hand, the goal is to understand what you are doing wrong, then read on. I'd say the first error going from left to right is passing the whole dataframe. I would have only passed the 'height' and 'weight' columns.

The next error, again going from left to right, is the use of `1:2` as the second argument to `apply`. You obviously want to do this "by rows" which mean you should use only `1`, i.e. the first dimension of the dataframe.

And the third error is using a function call rather than the function name. Functions with arguments in parentheses don't work when an R function (meaning `apply` in this case) is expecting a function name or an anonymous function as illustrated in comments.

Fourth error is not assigning the value to a column in your dataframe. So this probably would have succeeded in making the desired extra column via the `apply` method. But, as noted in comments this is not the most efficient method.:

```
Student$bmi_val <- apply(Student[ ,c("weight", "height")], bmi)
 # didn't want my column name to be the same as the function name
```

The `apply` function was actually designed to work with matrices and arrays, so for many purposes it is ill-suited when used with dataframes. In this case where all the arguments to the bmi function are numeric and you can control the order of argument in the first argument to match the x and y positions, it's arguably an acceptable strategy, but not most R-ish method. When working with dates or factor variables, you should definitely avoid `apply`.